# If $a\sin(x) +b\sin(2x)+c\sin(3x)=0$ for every real $x$, then $a=b=c=0$.

Tags: trigonometry

How to solve the following without calculus? In a trigonometric manner.

> If $$a\sin(x) +b\sin(2x)+c\sin(3x)=0$$
> for every real $x$, then $a=b=c=0$.

I solved the problem by integrating and using the result that $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin(px) \sin(qx) dx = 0$$
That's why i wanted an easier proof.

Comment: You should know that the community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort makes a poor impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Comment: Using vectors will be much more easier

Comment: @Blue,i have written what i thought of the way of solving it. It lacks info because i have to master latex, first. After that, i will be able to elaborate my own work before asking for help.

Comment: @Learner,what about complex numbers? I think that sin(px) can be written as the imaginary part, using the Euler's equation, and after that, the exponential. Being always positive, it follows that a=b=c=0.i may be wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple. Plug $x = \frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{3}, \frac{\pi}{4}$ into the equation to obtain three linear equations in $a,b,c$. You should obtain $a = b = c = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose particular values for $x$ and then solve the linear equation.

For example,

\begin{cases}
x=\frac{\pi}{2}\Rightarrow a-c=0\\
x=\frac{\pi}{3}\Rightarrow \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}(a+b)=0\\
x=\frac{2\pi}{3}\Rightarrow \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}(a-b)=0\\
\end{cases}

Solve the equation then you can get $a=b=c=0$

Answer (score 1):

If this is supposed to be true for any $x$, using Taylor series
$$a\sin(x) +b\sin(2x)+c\sin(3x)=$$ $$ (a+2 b+3 c)x-\frac{a+8 b+27 c}{6} x^3 +\frac{a+32 b+243
   c}{120} x^5 +O\left(x^7\right)$$ Set the coefficients equal to solve, solve the three linear equations in $(a,b,c)$ and obtain $a=b=c=0$

Comment: If you use Taylor series, you use calculus and even heavy calculus... which is forbidden here.